# Has this spider been seen before?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, the-mandalorian

In season 2 episode 2 of The Mandalorian, a vicious, spider-like species plays heavily into the story.

[image: spiders]

I instantly recognized them as very similar in appearance to the [krykn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Krykna) found on Atollon in the animated show Rebels.

[image: krykna]

Are these creatures the same or related in any way?

Comment: I could have sworn you fight these things in a bunch of places in the `Jedi Fallen Order` game

Comment: @Derek Those were Wyyyschokk on Kashyyyk. More real-world-spider-looking than these unknown spiders.

Comment: https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/star-wars-the-mandalorian-spiders-krykna-knobby-white-ralph-mcquarrie-spoilers/

Comment: "*Interestingly enough, **both the krykna and the spiders in The Mandalorian are inspired by a piece of McQuarrie art for The Empire Strikes Back that depicts a giant spider laying eggs on Dagobah as a young Luke Skywalker looks on in awe**. The creature in the piece, which never actually appeared in the movie, became known as the “knobby white spider.”*"

Comment: They appear the same, I watched the episode again yesterday and I heard them also go by the name krykn when the mando was speaking to the x-wing pilots.

Comment: @Starwarsfananonymous - I don't remember that. Is there confirmation somewhere that we can link to?

Comment: In episode 1, Mando fought a dragon. In episode 2, he fought ice spiders. What next? [Grumkins and snarks](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Grumkins_and_Snarks)?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - We can only hope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### This is a new species

Lucasfilm's Creative Art Manager, Phil Szostak, has confirmed [via Twitter](https://twitter.com/Aviriia/status/1324639989448249347?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1324640601602576384%7Ctwgr%5Eshare_3&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fscreenrant.com%2Fmandalorian-season-2-episode-2-spiders-species-krykna%2F) that while both  creatures are inspired by the same Ralph McQuarrie art depicting a giant spider on Degobah, they are a completely different species.

[image: knobby white spider]

[image]